# create list item in sharepoint using Graph API in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a new list item to an existing list in sharepoint using spfx react with Graph API.

```
 const obj: string = JSON.stringify({
      'LinkTitle': `Item ${new Date()}`,
      'Contactlist': '555555555',
      'CompanyName': 'dfvb',
      'Country': 'asd'
    });

  this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
        client
          .api("sites('root')/lists('Contactlist')/items")
          .post(obj).then(() => {
            console.log('obj' + obj);
          });
      });
```

but it is posting a list item with no values.

[sharepoint list item with no values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJpmX.png)

I want the obj to be posted in Contactlist list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample test demo for your reference.

```
const obj: string = JSON.stringify(
  {
    "fields": {
      'Title': 'Lin',
      'Company': 'Microsoft'
    }
  }
  );
this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    client         
     .api("/sites/siteid/lists/77d9ee4c-9142-40d1-8edb-9bdfd226be2a/items")
     .header('Content-Type','application/json')
     .version("v1.0")
      .post(obj, (err, res, success) => {
        if (err) {  
        console.log(err);                 
        }                
        if (success)
        {
          console.log("success");
        }            
      })
  });
```